# How to compile all javascript assets locally to see size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am writing an application and want to see how big my javascript is getting. Is there a way to compile it as one file on my local machine so I can check?

Answer (score 1):

try `rake assets:precompile` and look into the `public/assets` folder